# Discord YAGPDB.xyz Bot Custom Command: Get Message from ID (golang)

Tags: discord

I'm both a Discord and Golang newbie and have run into an issue.

I'm trying to help someone create a custom command to get Discord's YAGPDB.xyz bot to move a message from one thread to another.  The main script does the actual job but the output is a little wrong: we want it to output the actual owner of the message (and timestamp) but it states that I (the person running the command) am the owner.

I've narrowed it down to the fact that when I put the message ID as a parameter, it stays as an int and I need to fetch/instantiate a Message so I can access its properties, like the author, as according to this:
https://docs.yagpdb.xyz/commands/custom-commands#the-message-template
There appears to be no specific argument of 'message' type, although there are things like *channel* and *member*:
https://docs.yagpdb.xyz/commands/custom-commands#require-arguments

So I have created a test script just to get the author details of a message:

```
{{$args := parseArgs 1 "Syntax is : '!getauthor (.MessageID to move)'"
    (carg "int" "message ID")}}

{{$message:= ($args.Get 0)}}
{{$message.Author}}
```

This is the output:

```
An error caused the execution of the custom command template to stop:
Failed executing CC #9, line 5, row 10: executing "CC #9" at <$message.Author>: can't evaluate field Author in type int
4    {{$message:= ($args.Get 0)}}
5    {{$message.Author}}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did it with `getMessage`

```
{{$args := parseArgs 2 "Syntax is : '!move-msg (.MessageID to move) (.ChannelID Source Channel ID)'"
    (carg "int" "message ID")
        (carg "int" "source channel ID")}}
 
{{$messageId := $args.Get 0}}
{{$sourceChannelId := $args.Get 1}}
{{$message := getMessage $sourceChannelId $messageId}}

Author: {{$message.Author.Username}}, Created: {{$message.Timestamp.Parse.String}}
```

prints this out:

```
Author: xxxxx, Created: 2021-12-16 22:14:33.586 +0000 UTC
```